# iterate through an array in a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

So, I'm still very new to Backbone.  My question is this:  I have a collection that is made like this:

```
...
isCollection: true,
parse: function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'ok') {
        this.page = response.result.page;
        this.count = response.result.count;
        this.total = response.result.total;
        this.sort = response.result.sort;
        this.ascending = response.result.ascending;
        this.myReports = response.result.results;
        return this;
    } else {

    }
```

Where this.myReports is an array of objects.  My question is how do I iterate over the array (myReports)?  Do I have to convert it to a collection?  If I try to use .each, i get an error about .each not being supported.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `myCollection.each` on a Backbone collection, you are essentially calling Underscore's [each](http://underscorejs.org/#each) method, but it is being presented to you a bit nicer as a `Backbone.Collection` method.

You could just use the method on the array:

```
_.each(this.myReports, function (report) {
  // do whatever with report
})
```

Whether you should convert it to a backbone collection is another question. If you want to store models in it, or use any of the `Backbone.Collection` functionality, then sure, convert it using the each method above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try iterating through it like a simple js array?

something like:

```
for(var i in myArray){
   var item = myArray[i];
   //dosomething
}
```

> Maybe it's worth trying underscorejs for advanced array features.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the elements of `response.result.results` into the collection this way:

```
parse: function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'ok') {
        this.page = response.result.page;
        this.count = response.result.count;
        this.total = response.result.total;
        this.sort = response.result.sort;
        this.ascending = response.result.ascending;
        return response.result.results;
    } else {

    }
}
```

Now if `fetch`ing the collection succeeds, and `response.status` is `'ok'`, then:

- your collection will have fields called `page`, `count`, `total`, `sort` and `ascending`,
- these fields will contain the values you get as the fields of `response.result`,
- the `length` of the collection will be the `length` of `response.result.results`, and
- **the items of the collection will be the items of `response.result.results`, so you can iterate over them inside the `success` handler of `fetch`**.

If the `fetch` fails, or `response.status` is not `'ok'`, then the length of the collection will be zero. The fields `page`, `count`, `total`, `sort` and `ascending` will be `undefined`, unless you define them somewhere, for example in `initialize` or in the `else` branch inside the above `parse` function.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/rTxWg/) is a working example.** The output is printed in the console, so e.g. in Chrome, press F12 and change to the Console tab. Anyway, since Backbone collections have a method called `sort`, I would change the name of the `sort` field to something else (`sorted`, `toBeSorted`, etc. - I don't know the semantics of this field).